# Set values from other table based on join in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

This is a very simple question, sorry, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'd like to add values from table X to table A based on a join. My SQL command is straight-forward (and discussed in several posts here):

```
UPDATE tableA SET n = x.numpts 
FROM tableA AS a, tableX AS x WHERE a.id = x.id;
```

This should in my eyes add the values of `numpts` to column `n` in `tableA` where the id of `tableA` is equal to the `id` in `tableX`. The command runs, but it sets all values in `column n` to 1. Maybe it's important to know that `tableX` has less rows than `tableA`. What am I doing wrong?

However, when I do a `SELECT`query instead of `UPDATE` I get the correctly matched result...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableA SET n = x.numpts 
FROM tableX AS x WHERE tableA.id = x.id;
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick answers! Works now.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE tableA  
SET n = tableX.numpts 
FROM tableX  
WHERE tableA.id = tableX.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful.  If `id` appears multiple times in `tableX`, then you want to aggregate *before* joining.  So this may be what you want:

```
UPDATE tableA
    SET n = x.numpts 
    FROM (SELECT x.id, SUM(x.numpts) as numpts
          FROM tableX x
          GROUP BY x.id
         ) x
    WHERE a.id = x.id;
```

If duplicates are not an issue, then both Roman and Oto have provided the correct syntax for Postgres.